# python xgboost on mac install

Tags: python, macos, installation, xgboost

I am trying to install xgboost on my Mac for Python 3.4 but I'm getting the following error after `pip3 setup.py install`:

```
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/_x/rkkz7tjj42g9n8lqq5r0ry000000gn/T/pip-build-2dc6bwf7/xgboost/setup.py", line 28, in <module>

    execfile(libpath_py, libpath, libpath)

NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined
```

When running it with the -v option to get the verbose output the error looks like this:

```
  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_x/rkkz7tjj42g9n8lqq5r0ry000000gn/T/pip-build-2dc6bwf7/xgboost
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 232, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 339, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 385, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 358, in run_egg_info
    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 749, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/_x/rkkz7tjj42g9n8lqq5r0ry000000gn/T/pip-build-2dc6bwf7/xgboost
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

OS: OSX El Capitan

Step-1: `cd xgboost; ./build.sh`
Step-2: `cd python-package; python setup.py install`

Comment: Works with OS X Yosemite also

Answer (score 2):

I think that xgboost is just available as Python 2 package over pip.
There are two possibilities to get it working.

1. You use Python 2 and install it with pip.
2. You can manually build xgboost for Python 3. Just download the source from github and build it: Open Terminal. check out from git: git clone https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost.git. build it: cd xgboost; make; cd wrapper; python.py setup install --user

Comment: 2. worked for me with cd xgboost; ./build.sh; python setup.py install --user

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should use

```
cd xgboost; cp make/minimum.mk ./config.mk; make -j4
```

instead of

```
cd xgboost; ./build.sh
```

as per the "Build On OSX" Section of build document

also perhaps this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211018/clang-error-errorunsupported-option-fopenmp-on-mac-osx-el-capitan-buildin/41624753#41624753)

Answer (score 0):

I've got many errors trying to install XGBoost on a Mac OS X Mojave 10.14 following the instructions [building from sources](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#building-on-osx). The worst one was when invoking CMake didn't work and the infamous clang: error unsupported option '-fopenmp'. A real C++ build / compilation nightmare...

Since I was not able to compile the native C++ library finally I succeeded using this workaround procedure:

1. Using brew to get the compiled library libxgboost.dylib:

   `brew install xgboost`

   Strangely enough, brew didn't install the whole thing!!??
2. Install the Python library:

   `git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost`

   `cd xgboost`
3. Install the compiled library libxgboost.dylib and link to it:

   `mkdir lib`

   `cd lib`

   `ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/xgboost/0.90/lib/libxgboost.dylib ./libxgboost.dylib`
4. Install the Python package

   `cd ../python-package`

   `sudo python3 setup.py install`

   Again, strangely enough, setup.py installs partially the egg package, so I have to copy manually the xgboost package directory to site-packages.

   `cp -r xgboost /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`

By the way, I've also to upgrade dask: `sudo pip3 install --upgrade dask`