# clang: error: : errorunsupported option '-fopenmp' on Mac OSX El Capitan building XGBoost

Tags: python, macos, gcc, xgboost

I'm trying to build [XGBoost](http://xgboost.readthedocs.org/) package for Python following [these instructions](http://xgboost.readthedocs.org/en/latest/build.html#building-on-osx):

> Here is the complete solution to use OpenMP-enabled compilers to install XGBoost. Obtain gcc-5.x.x with openmp support by `brew install gcc --without-multilib`. (brew is the de facto standard of apt-get on OS X. So installing HPC separately is not recommended, but it should work.):

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost; cp make/config.mk ./config.mk; make -j4
```

This error occurss precisely in the `make -j4` command.

Searching beforenad, I've tried these two solutions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19649634/clang-error-unsupported-option-static-libgcc-on-mac-osx-mavericks) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351219/cuda-clang-and-os-x-mavericks)), to no avail, except for the part to installing another gcc by fear of messing up everything.

Below is the `make` configuration file. It has none suspicious about.

```
#-----------------------------------------------------
#  xgboost: the configuration compile script
#
#  If you want to change the configuration, please use the following
#  steps. Assume you are on the root directory of xgboost.
#  First copy the this file so that any local changes will be ignored by git
#
#  $ cp make/config.mk .
#
#  Next modify the according entries, and then compile by
#
#  $ make
#
#  or build in parallel with 8 threads
#
#  $ make -j8
#----------------------------------------------------

# choice of compiler, by default use system preference.
# export CC = gcc
# export CXX = g++
# export MPICXX = mpicxx

# the additional link flags you want to add
ADD_LDFLAGS =

# the additional compile flags you want to add
ADD_CFLAGS =

# Whether enable openmp support, needed for multi-threading.
USE_OPENMP = 1

# whether use HDFS support during compile
USE_HDFS = 0

# whether use AWS S3 support during compile
USE_S3 = 0

# whether use Azure blob support during compile
USE_AZURE = 0

# Rabit library version,
# - librabit.a Normal distributed version.
# - librabit_empty.a Non distributed mock version,
LIB_RABIT = librabit.a

# path to libjvm.so
LIBJVM=$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/amd64/server

# List of additional plugins, checkout plugin folder.
# uncomment the following lines to include these plugins
# you can also add your own plugin like this
#
# XGB_PLUGINS += plugin/example/plugin.mk
```

Comment: Read the comments in the Makefile carefully.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You installed `gcc` with Homebrew, yet the error is from `clang`. That should simply mean that your default compiler still points to `clang` instead of the newly installed `gcc`. If you read the comments in the Makefile, you'll see the following lines:

```
# choice of compiler, by default use system preference.
# export CC = gcc
# export CXX = g++
# export MPICXX = mpicxx
```

and in your case, you don't want the system one.
Note: `gcc` for the system points to `clang`:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Instead, point those variables to something in `/usr/local/bin`, e.g.:

```
$ export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc
```

and similar for the other two variables, `CXX` and `MPICXX`, e.g.:

```
$ export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc;CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++;MPICXX=/usr/local/bin/mpicxx
```

Comment: In my system, the command `which gcc` gives me this: `/usr/bin/gcc
`. I then run the command in terminal: `export CC=/usr/bin/gcc`. The error still goes on. I`m not very expert in `gcc`, `make` and the like.

Comment: Try runnng `ls /usr/local/bin/gcc*` and I think it'l be `gcc-5` or somesuch. You need to use that with the `export CC=...` above.

Comment: The `ls /usr/local/bin/gcc*` gives me a list of links, one of them ends with `gcc-5`. Then I run the command `export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-5`. I also put this command in the make file configuration, to no avail. :(

Comment: Hei! the command `echo $CC` gives me the original `/usr/bin/gcc`. But the result of command `export` alone gives me a bunch of declares, one of them with the variable `CC` correctly pointing to `/usr/local/bin/gcc-5`. What the hell is goin on?

Comment: @srodriguex Note: *and similar for the other two variables.*. CXX abd MPICXX also need to be defined.

Comment: This saved my life.

Answer (score 9):

Sir, perhaps you should use

> cd xgboost; cp make/minimum.mk ./config.mk; make -j4

instead of

> cd xgboost; cp make/config.mk ./config.mk; make -j4

as per the "Build On OSX" Section of [build document](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html)

Comment: Doing the accepted answer then this has solved the problem for me.

Comment: this worked for me as well , but after performing the first step written above , Thanks

Comment: yes, you must first change the exports, i wonder if this is a bug or related to something else.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue I did the following: I realized I had `gcc` 6 installed, so I ran:

```
export CC=gcc-6
```

But it didn't work by itself, so I had to also:

```
export CXX=g++-6
```

This solved it for me. I'm in a Macbook Pro running macOS Sierra. You can also make those changes directly on XGBoost's Makefile if you want. For more info about this: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_on_Mac_OSX?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Unable to compile the native libxgboost.dylib library, maybe check this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59708019/1209842)