# Error when trying to install xgboost, Mac

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip

trying to install xgboost

pip3 install xgboost

this is the full output if that helps

Downloading xgboost-0.7.post3.tar.gz (450kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 460kB 247kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
++ pwd

+ oldpath=/private/tmp/pip-build-dz4iiw24/xgboost

+ cd ./xgboost/

+ [[ darwin16 == \d\a\r\w\i\n* ]]

+ LIB_XGBOOST=libxgboost.dylib

+ make lib/libxgboost.dylib -j4

Makefile:31: MAKE [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make]
```

- checked OK

```
c++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -I/private/tmp/pip-build-dz4iiw24/xgboost/xgboost/dmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -I/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/learner.o src/learner.cc
```

> build/learner.d

```
c++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -I/private/tmp/pip-build-dz4iiw24/xgboost/xgboost/dmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -I/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/logging.o src/logging.cc
```

> build/logging.d

```
c++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -I/private/tmp/pip-build-dz4iiw24/xgboost/xgboost/dmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -I/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/c_api/c_api.o
```

src/c_api/c_api.cc >build/c_api/c_api.d

```
c++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -I/private/tmp/pip-build-dz4iiw24/xgboost/xgboost/dmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -I/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/c_api/c_api_error.o src/c_api/c_api_error.cc >build/c_api/c_api_error.d

clangclangclang: error: : : error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'unsupported option '-fopenmp'clang


error: : unsupported option '-fopenmp'error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'


make: *** [build/c_api/c_api_error.o] Error 1

make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

make: *** [build/c_api/c_api.o] Error 1

make: *** [build/logging.o] Error 1

make: *** [build/learner.o] Error 1

+ echo -----------------------------
-----------------------------

+ echo 'Building multi-thread xgboost failed'

Building multi-thread xgboost failed

+ echo 'Start to build single-thread xgboost'

Start to build single-thread xgboost

+ make clean

Makefile:31: MAKE [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make] 
- checked OK

rm -f -rf build build_plugin lib bin *~ */*~ */*/*~ */*/*/*~ */*.o */*/*.o 
*/*/*/*.o #xgboost

rm -f -rf build_tests *.gcov tests/cpp/xgboost_test

cd R-package/src; rm -f -rf rabit src include dmlc-core amalgamation *.so 
*.dll; cd /private/tmp/pip-build-dz4iiw24/xgboost/xgboost

/bin/sh: line 0: cd: R-package/src: No such file or directory
+ make lib/libxgboost.dylib -j4 USE_OPENMP=0

Makefile:31: MAKE [/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make] 
- checked OK

Makefile:43: /private/tmp/pip-build-dz4iiw24/xgboost/xgboost/dmlc-
core/make/dmlc.mk: No such file or directory

make: *** No rule to make target `/private/tmp/pip-build-dz4iiw24/xgboost/xgboost/dmlc-core/make/dmlc.mk'.  Stop.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/tmp/pip-build-dz4iiw24/xgboost/setup.py", line 37, in <module>
    LIB_PATH = libpath['find_lib_path']()
  File "/private/tmp/pip-build-dz4iiw24/xgboost/xgboost/libpath.py", line 49, in find_lib_path
    'List of candidates:\n' + ('\n'.join(dll_path)))
XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Library in the candidate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?
List of candidates:
/private/tmp/pip-build-dz4iiw24/xgboost/xgboost/libxgboost.dylib
/private/tmp/pip-build-dz4iiw24/xgboost/xgboost/../../lib/libxgboost.dylib
/private/tmp/pip-build-dz4iiw24/xgboost/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.dylib
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/xgboost/libxgboost.dylib

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-dz4iiw24/xgboost/
```

Comment: [unsupported option '-fopenmp' clang](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36211162/7976758) — use `gcc` instead of `clang`. xgboost requires `gcc` on Mac.

Comment: [make: *** No rule to make target …/dmlc.mk. Stop.](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1997) — `git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost`

Answer (score 0):

Try "conda install py-xgboost". This worked for me.