# How to install and run a program with openmp c/c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I need to install OpenMP on my Mac and use it in CLion. I re-installed gcc, confirmed I have it, /usr/bin/local/gcc-7. Do not understand if this comes with OpenMP or if I need to install something extra.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(lab_3)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fopenmp")

add_executable(lab_3 main.cpp)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main() {

#pragma omp parallel for

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        std::cout << "This is thread #" << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Error message:

> clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36211162/2850543. You're compiling with clang, not gcc.

Comment: Can you explain further please?

Comment: OK, I was able to fix it by going into CLion and changing the default compiler to gcc. Thanks for pointing this out, did not even know what clang was.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clang: error: : errorunsupported option '-fopenmp' on Mac OSX El Capitan building XGBoost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211018/clang-error-errorunsupported-option-fopenmp-on-mac-osx-el-capitan-buildin)