# R package 'data.table' cannot be installed. - mac air

Tags: r

My laptop is a mac pro. The OS version is 10.15 Catalina. The r studio version is 1.2.5001. The R version is 3.6.1.

I tried to install "WGCNA", but it failed because of the following error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘data.table’
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘WGCNA’
* removing ‘/Users/zhaoboao/Library/R/3.6/library/WGCNA’
```

Therefore, I installed 'data.table', but it also failed because of the following error:

```
* installing *source* package ‘data.table’ ...
** package ‘data.table’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -fopenmp -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c assign.c -o assign.o
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make: *** [assign.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘data.table’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/data.table’
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem? I really appreciate it!

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211018/clang-error-errorunsupported-option-fopenmp-on-mac-osx-el-capitan-buildin) may help

Comment: It appears that I don't have GCC on my computer. I will go download one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all...welcome to what I think is the best online community for `R` users! (though others may disagree)

To address your question, I absolutely empathize with your frustration. I also had a horrid time trying to get the package `data.table` to install in `R` after updating to Catalina. Being a little better than a novice with the terminal at best, I still need a moderate amount of hand holding which I think accounts for many others as well. The only set of step by step directions that worked for me was laid out at [The Coatless Professor](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/).

On a side note, I did install updated versions of `clang` and `gfortran` using `clang-8.0.0` and `gfortran-6.1`, respectively. Both of these can be found on the R for Mac OS X Development Tools and Libraries by selecting this [link](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/). However, if you use the stepwise directions, I'd advise installing them when it is brought up.

I only bring this up because it is easy to miss but the very last thing is to make sure you use the correct version of `clang` when running step #3 under INSTALLING THE CLANG7 R BINARY. In my case, I had to change the version 7 of `clang` to 8 by amending `echo 'PATH="/usr/local/clang7/bin:${PATH}"' >> ~/.Renviron` to `echo 'PATH="/usr/local/clang8/bin:${PATH}"' >> ~/.Renviron`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to hear it! Thank for letting me know and for the +1.